# How to add Content Control before bookmark?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I want macro to add Content Control before bookmark. I am having trouble figuring out syntax for "before" part since `.Range.InsertBefore` works only with string.

Please give me some direction how to change my code to make new Content Conrols to be inserted before bookmark.

My current code for inserting Content Control:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim objCC As ContentControl
          'it inserts Content control after bookmark, not before, how to change this part?
    Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(0, ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("VP_pav").Range)
    objCC.Title = "Test"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmarks aren't substantial "objects" in the text flow, the way a character is, so it's not possible to insert anything immediately before a bookmark. The insertion position would have to be moved at least one character back from the bookmark.

The only way to have the bookmark directly after the content control is to delete and recreate the bookmark. Here's an example. Note the use of `Range` objects to keep track of where the content control is and where the bookmark is. This example is for an "I-beam" bookmark: a bookmark that is a single position, not a range of characters.

```
Sub InsertCCbeforeBookmark()
    Dim bkm As Bookmark, sBookmarkName As String
    Dim rngBookmark As Word.Range, rngCC As Word.Range
    Dim objCC As ContentControl

    sBookmarkName = "VP_pav"
    Set bkm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(sBookmarkName)
    Set rngBookmark = bkm.Range
    Set rngCC = rngBookmark.Duplicate
    rngCC.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    Set objCC = ActiveDocument.Contentcontrols.Add(0, rngCC)
    rngBookmark.Start = objCC.Range.End
    rngBookmark.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
    bkm.Delete
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add sBookmarkName, rngBookmark
    objCC.title = "Test"

End Sub
```